# Java : relational database vs static variable

Tags: java, server, hashmap, static-variables

I have a web application in which I'm maintaining many static Maps to store my relevant information. Since the application is deployed on a server. Each and every hit to the server side java uses these maps to match the key and get appropriate result and send back to the client side. My code contains a rank and retrieval feature so I have to read the entire keySet of each of these Maps.

My question is:

**1. Is working with static variables better than storing this data in a local embedded DB like Apache Derby and then using it?**

**2. The use of this data is very frequent. So if I use database will that be faster approach? Since I read the full keyset the where clause may not come handy in many operations.**

**3. How does the server's memory gets impacted on holding data in static variables?**

My no. of maps are fixed but the size of the Maps keeps increasing? Please suggest the better solution.

Comment: Wouldn't a **caching system** be more appropriate? It would be in memory and has more possibilities for scaling...

Comment: In that case I'll have to monitor data changes, and read the updated data rather than cache. And thats what my question is how will having data in cache impact server memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be saved regularly an embedded database like H2 makes sense. You then also have snapshots of the data, and development, structural changes are a bit more safe.

A real database also has an incredible power behind it: concurrency, caching and so on. An embedded (when file based) database less so.

The problem with maps is that the data extraction can become several indirections. It is more versatile to have SQL queries with joins on the tables.
So SQL is more abstract (does not prescribe the actual query implementation), and easier to test. SQL for instance releases the developer of programming reports.

So go for a database IMHO, when you are really doing hard work.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to consider is to store the data searched in map when it's searched.

For instance, if a user searches for something specific, that something is stored in the map so that the next user who searches for that gets the data directly from the map rather than the database.

There are some downsides though, as you need to make sure that if the data is changed on the database, the hashmap/cache should be cleared or updated with the new data, as to prevent feeding outdated data to the user.

As for the impact on the server's memory, it depends on the size of the data you're storing. It's hard to give you a precise answer, but you can however test that on your own:

```
long memoryBefore = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
// populate your map
long memoryAfter = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
System.out.println(memoryBefore - memoryAfter);
```

That should give you the amount of bytes used (more or less, depending on the operations you run between memoryBefore and memoryAfter, as you may have instantiated other classes/variables unrelated to the hashmap)